# Handling dynamic query parameter in CXF restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, cxf-client

I want to handle dynamic query parameter in CXF RESTful service.

My concern here is from the service end i will not be knowing the number of parameters/key names that comes with the request. Could you please let me know how we can handle this situation/scenario.

**For example my client code will look like below ,**

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("foo", "hello");
params.put("bar", "world");

WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://url"); 
for (Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    webClient.query(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

Response res = webClient.get();
```

The below code works fine for me,

```
public String getDynamicParamter(@Context UriInfo ui){
    System.out.println(ui.getQueryParameters());
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = ui.getQueryParameters();
    Set keys=map.keySet();
    Iterator<String > it = keys.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String key= it.next();
        System.out.println("Key --->"+key+"  Value"+map.get(key).toString());
    }
    return "";

}
```

However , could you please let me know the below,

1. Whether it is standard way?
2. And, is there any other ways to achieve it?

**CXF version : 3.1.4**

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Getting the query parameters from the `UriInfo`

As you already guessed, there are some methods in [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters--) API that will provide you the query parameters:

- [`getQueryParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters--): Returns an unmodifiable map containing the names and values of query parameters of the current request. All sequences of escaped octets in parameter names and values are decoded, equivalent to [`getQueryParameters(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters-boolean-).
- [`getQueryParameters(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters-boolean-): Returns an unmodifiable map containing the names and values of query parameters of the current request.

The [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) can be injected in a resource class member using the [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation:

```java
@Path("/foo")
public class SomeResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @GET
    public Response someMethod() {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        ...
    }
}
```

And can be injected in a method parameter:

```java
@GET
public Response someMethod(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    ...
}
```

To get the unparsed query string, do the following:

```
@GET
public Response someMethod(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    String query = uriInfo.getRequestUri().getQuery();
    ...
}
```

### Getting the query parameters from the `HttpServletRequest`

You could achieve a similiar result by injecting the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) with the [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation, just like the [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters--) mentioned above. Here are a few methods that can be useful:

- [`getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--): Returns an immutable map containing the names and values of parameters sent in the request.
- [`getParameterNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames--): Returns an [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) containing the names of the parameters contained in the request.
- [`getParameterValues(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-): Returns an array containing all of the values the given request parameter.
- [`getParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-): Returns the value of a request parameter. Should only be used when you are sure the parameter has only one value. Otherwise, only the first value for the given parameter name will be returned.
- [`getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString--): Returns the query string that is contained in the request URL.